BrowserSync throws aggregate Error with Gulp 5/Node.js v.20
I am attempting to rebuild my gulpfile.js after upgrading to Gulp 5 and the most recent stable version of Node.js (20.11.1). The gulpfile below works just fine with Node.js version 16.14.0, but is broken after around v.18. I get a message that says "aggregateerror" which I cannot figure out how to debug. I have Googled the crap out of this, but to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my gulpfile:
const { src, dest, gulp, watch, series, parallel } = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

function reload(done) {
   browserSync.reload();
   done();
}

function serve(done) {
   browserSync.init({
      proxy: 'mysite.ddev.site',
      injectChanges: true
   });
   done();
}

function watchTask(done) {
   watch('css/scss/**/*.scss', series(cssTask, reload));
   done();
}

function cssTask() {
   return (
        src('css/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(dest('css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
   );
}

exports.default = series(serve, watchTask)


I have Gulp v 4.0.2
In my case error create by easy-logger: node_modules/easy-loggger/index.js
line 210 as is:
    var incomingMessage = typeof msg === "string" ? msg : msg();

with this code Gulp not run and get errors in console.
I replaced it to
     let incomingMessage = typeof msg === "String" ? msg : msg;

After i do it i get "AggregateError" message while gulp starting, but it works.
